# Create log in/out with HTML and PHP by adding inputted name/password to a txt file, without SQL?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Is it possible to create a log in/out feature without JS and SQL? I don't know if it's possible to first get the submitted username/password from an html input, and save it to a txt file with PHP.
This way, if the username already exists in the txt file, and the password matches, the user can log in successfully.

Here's my current HTML code:

```
  <form method="get" action="form.php">
  <label>Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" autocomplete = "off">
  <label>Password</label>
  <input type="text" id="password" name="password" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I plan to store the name and password to a txt file with PHP; how might I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this is certainly possible. Did you encounter, or do you foresee, a problem?

Comment: Make sure you don't make the text file web accessible. Also make sure you hash passwords.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Yes- I just don't know how to do that... If I add the username/passwords to the txt file, will the txt file clear its contents if I load my website on a different browser or something? Thanks! (Im new to php and I don't know really anything yet :(

Comment: There are many tutorials on the topic of storing data to a text file. Make sure you are appending to the file, not overwriting.

Comment: OK, I understand it can be a problem when you don't know how to do this all. Protecting credentials is important, of course. The way to find out is too search for it, and experiment. It's a slow process. A question here has to be focused on a very specific problem, preferably accompanied by the code in question.

Comment: `the txt file clear its contents if I load my website on a different browser`...the text file knows nothing about any browsers. The only way that could happen is if you specifically write code to clear the file when a new session is started, or make a different file per session, or something like that.

Comment: But seriously, why do you want to do this? Concurrency with text files is a nightmare, so is searching efficienctly for data within one. This won't scale to more than a handful of users. It won't really teach you much, if anything, about how people implement this sort of thing in the real world. There are a lot of good reasons why people use SQL databases with their web applications (not just for authentication, but in general)

Comment: P.S. For future reference when using Stackoverflow: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/why-is-is-it-possible-to-a-poorly-worded-question)

Comment: P.P.S. WARNING: Writing an access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. It is very much _not_ a sensible topic for a beginnner / inexperienced programmer who is unfamiliar with the general basics of web applications. Any [modern development framework](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in.

Comment: While your question can be answered with a simple and straight forward "yes", I'd not recommend (as others as well) to do so. When you want to start with reading and writing text-files consider a different use-case from anything access related, better something that is not vital to a system due to the mentioned issues. You can also let your webserver handle the login and not take care about within PHP at all (but the webserver will give you the username). If you like some more boring tech: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

Comment: @Adyson Thanks Adyson and Hakre! I'm really new to this stuff, so i'll prob experiment with this; but what is a more secure way to do log-in things?

Comment: The most secure way usually is to use an established, well-tested mechanism such as the ones built into popular frameworks, or integrating with a 3rd-party authentication provider such as Google or Microsoft etc. But if you insist on writing your own, using files for storage isn't inherently _insecure_ in and of itself (as long as the file isn't stored insecurely or in a public location of course!), that wasn't quite what we were saying. The point was that it causes problems related to efficiency, performance, scalability. SQL is great at finding data in a database _really fast, concurrently_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do u really wanna do it? u can store it in database also. Anyways if u really want it then, you can use 'file_put_contents'.
And edit ur submit button to:
`<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">`

php code:

```
<?php
 if(isset($_GET['name'])){
    $name=$_GET['name'];
    $password= $_GET['password'];
    $data= "Name: $name\nPassword: $password\n";
    $file="data.txt";
    file_put_contents($file, $data);
    echo("Data entered");
}
?>
```